# Do we have to do two image layout transitions when creating a new image?

Tags: vulkan

When I want to upload an image to device local memory I first create an image, then I issue a layout transition to transition from UNDEFINED to TRANSFER DESTINATION, then I do a copy buffer to image. Then I transition from TRANSFER DESTINATION to whatever layout I want. Is there a more direct way to do this? In vkCmdCopyBufferToImage there is an argument 'dstImageLayout'. I made the mistake of thinking that the argument tells Vulkan to transition the image automatically to that layout as it copies it. This 'would' seem to me to be more efficient and make more sense, but it's not what I thought it was.

Is there a way to do this without two layout transitions? It's OK if there isn't, I think this is the proper way to do it, I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: "*This 'would' seem to me to be more efficient*" What would be particularly efficient about it?

Comment: @NicolBolas Well the layout transition would be done as it's being transferred to the destination image, if that's even possible, as opposed to doing another layout transition.

Answer (score 2):

You do not strictly speaking have to perform two layout transitions. The `GENERAL` layout can be used with basically anything. So you could just transition it once, copy into it, and use it from there.

However, this would be pointless for several reasons. First, it's reasonable to assume that any layout transition *from* `UNDEFINED` will be a no-op as far as actual GPU processing is concerned. Such transitions conceptually trash any of the contents of the image, so there's no point in having the GPU do anything to the image's bytes.

Second, in order to use an image you copied into, you will need *some kind* of explicit synchronization between the copy operation and the usage of it. Whatever that synchronization is, it may as well include a layout transition. The GPU is going to have to make sure the two don't overlap, so you may as well toss in a layout transition.

Lastly, using `GENERAL` like this is a premature optimization and therefore should be avoided unless you have profiling data telling you that layout transitions are an *actual* performance problem (or you have no other choice).

Answer (score 0):

`LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST` is by definition the most efficient target for copies. So no other layout can be more efficient.

Some actual GPU might perform no actual layout transitions. The layout system is just a general API abstraction. It is not even defined what "layout" actually is, and the GPU driver may use the API concept whichever way it is beneficial for it.

If a particular picky GPU needs the image in such specific layout when copying into it, then there's no way around it, and there would be two layout transitions no matter how you shape the API. If the GPU does not need it, then it will just elide the layout transitions on its own.